# list of lists to list without depth

Tags: prolog

i was trying to create a function that takes a list of lists an gives back a new list with the elements of the original one but withoun depth.
f.e:

```
?- function([a,[b,c],d],X).  
X = [a,b,c,d]  
?- function([[a],[[b]],[c,[d]]],X).  
X = [a,b,c,d]
```

and i found in a manual the following code:

```
function([],[]):- !.  
function([H|T],[H|R]):- \+ lst(H), !, function(T,R).  
function([H|T],L):- function(H,L1), function(T,L2),
append(L1,L2,T).
```

Unfortunately it says nowhere which function lst(H) is.
Plus i cannot understand what exactly lst() does and define it and as a result it comes out as undefined.

If anyone  could understand how lst should be defined or simply give me an alternative about how to do what i'm trying,i'd be grateful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that lst(X) should be true iff X is a list. In SWI, an equivalent predicate is called is_list/1. In your code, + is used for negation, but i am familiar with `\+`. (ah, i see, the site swallows the `\`)

Edit: The last T in the last row should be L:

```
function([H|T],L):- function(H,L1), function(T,L2), append(L1,L2,L).
```

I tried it and it works in SWI.

Comment: thnx for the tip,i tried to replace it with is_list but unfortunately the only result i keep getting is "false".the code must be wrong somewhere else i guess..

Answer (score 2):

As Pavel already said, try is_list/1 in SWI or write your own simple predicate that is true if its argument is a list. Even better, write a version that throws an instantiation error if the top list still contains variables on the grounds that there is insufficient information on what to do: The variable might later be instantiated to a list, in which case the predicate should remove the nesting but obviously couldn't at the time it was called.

Comment: is_list didn't work,and i'm afraid i'm too new to prolog to compose a code that does what you describe..but thnx anyway!